# What is the 'app.use' equivalent in nextjs middleware?

Tags: express, next.js, middleware

I have just come across [next.js middlware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware). I am coming from using [express.js](https://expressjs.com/) and I was wondering what is the equivalent of `app.use()` in [next.js middlware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware).

Comment: If you're asking about built-in equivalent to `app.use`, there isn't one.

Comment: Did you find out how this works? I'm struggling with this too.

Comment: There isn't one. You can use the [next-connect npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-connect) to simulate expressJs like middleware. @Ilir

Comment: @YulePale yes i've been using next-connect in my project and its working fine but i wanted to convert my API routes to pure Nextjs. Anyway if i find a solution i will write it here.